# Twitter sign up with next auth not working

Tags: next-auth

[image]

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
import prisma from "../../../lib/prismadb"
import InstagramProvider from "next-auth/providers/instagram";
import TwitterProvider from "next-auth/providers/twitter";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";

export default NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  
  providers: [
    InstagramProvider({
      clientId: process.env.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET
    }),
    TwitterProvider({
      clientId: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET,
      version: "2.0",
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET
    })

    
  ],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjeKb.png)I am trying to  make a website with option to sign up with twitter with next auth.

I have watched all the videos about setting it up but nothing works and this error still appears
I have the twitter client and the twitter client id in the .env provided from twitter

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the redirect URl which has to have "/api/auth/callback/twitter" in the end of your domain